# Application Record, variable in partial, Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, partial

I have document with advertisement under _feed_ad.html in views/application folder and when I put there <% title @advert.name %> I get this error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. Should I initialize variable advert somewhere? I have scaffold Advert previously, but it does not help. Something is missing.

Comment: yes indeed you must initialize @advert in the controller that is delivering the page in which the partial resides.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to declare the variable **@advert** in the controllers where this partial was used. Or rewrite ***_feed_ad.htm*** in such a way:

```rb
<% title advert.name %>
```

and render

```rb
  = render 'application/feed_ad', advert: @advert
```

which is more preferable